# HTTP Authentication for HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, http-authentication, authenticator

My app needs to connect to multiple servers, each with their own username/password pairs. However The example provided in Android's javadoc does not consider multiple hosts with different sets of username/password:

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

   });
 }
```

This sets the VM-wide authentication handler, and has no way to identify which host we are trying to connect to. Is there a way that I can use HttpUrlConenction and handle HTTP Authentication with different user/passes for different hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Authenticator's [getRequestingHost()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html#getRequestingHost%28%29) method.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        if (this.getRequestingHost() != null)
            if (this.getRequestingHost().contains("a-site.com")
                return new PasswordAuthentication(aUsername, aPassword.toCharArray());
            else if (this.getRequestingHost().contains("b-site.com")
                return new PasswordAuthentication(bUsername, bPassword.toCharArray());
        return null;
    });
})
```